# Bootstrap Navigation destroying site width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

Nav is changing site width. I don't know why's that.
I thought that's because margins or padding, but couldn't find any way to fix the problem.
I came to conclusion that  is cousing problems, but I don't know why's that.
Please help!

HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">IT SPECIALIST</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" id="active" href="#">GŁÓWNA</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              O NAS
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Zespół</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Partnerzy</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Facebook Fanpage</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              OFERTA
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Odzyskiwanie Danych</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wsparcie dla twojej firmy</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="nav-link" href="#">USŁUGI DLA FIRM I OSÓB PRYWATNYCH</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="nav-link" href="#">DLACZEGO MY</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="nav-link" href="#">ZGŁOŚ AWARIĘ</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

I deleted whole css code, and nothing changed, but in case you need it here it is:

CSS code:

```
body {
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 1vw;
}

.navbar button {
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.navbar .dropdown-item:hover, .navbar #nav-link:hover, .navbar #active {
  background-color: #5394dd;
  color: white;
}

.navbar .nav-item {
  margin-left: 0.5vw;
}

.navbar .nav-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 1vw;
}
```

Edit 1:
`row` is cousing the problem, while using nav, without any rows, and columns, navigation is taking whole site width, nothing more.
So, is there any other way, to center site, like this?

Comment: Whatever code you posted, is this enclosed in a div with the `row` class?

Comment: Yes, it is. I will edit that

Comment: Bootstrap has standard CSS included which takes care of margins and padding. By adding more of our own CSS we're adding more opportunities for things to go wrong. Here are the spacing docs for Bootstrap 4 ... You can simply add `p` for padding and `m` for margin ... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Even without any additional css code, problem still appears.

Comment: OK, so it might be because you have the navbar inside 2 columns. The first column is `col-2`, the second column is `col-8`. Both of these have different widths on different screens  col-8 is trying to organise its width inside col-2 and then your navbar is simply doing its best to organise it's width within both of the columns. There are at least 2 width instructions from those columns plus all your width and margin instructions in your CSS. Just put navbar on it's own and not inside any divs.

Comment: Yes, this way it's working, but it takes the whole widht of the site, where I wanted it do be only in the middle part.

Comment: We're getting there though :) So add one div around the `nav-bar` which will be.... `<div class="container">`

Comment: @OskarB If you only want to have the nav within a certain width, maybe use a `container`? That way, it'll be in the middle in all medium to large screens.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob haha, same time. But yeah. `container` should be the solution to all problems here.

Comment: @Siddarth Bhansali That's why we're here Bro. Can't fix my own website problems though innit. Have a great day :)

Comment: That's genius! Thank you very much for help. It worked! But now it leaves some spare space on mobile device, is there a way, to max out width only on mobile?

Comment: `<div class="container-lg p-0">` fixed all problems, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all `col`'s from around the Navbar and add a `container` instead.

```
<div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
       <!--Your nav content here-->
   </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how it is destroying the site's width but try this adding this to your styling:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```